# Formally stating hypotheses with two parts

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I'm trying to state my hypotheses formally for my dissertation, but I'm getting my brain in a twist here.

H0: (µ1- µ2) – (µ3- µ4) ≤ 0: The mean difference in response time between low load incompatible trials and low load neutral trials will be equal to or lower than the mean difference in response times between high load incompatible trials and high load neutral trials.

H1: (µ1- µ2) – (µ3- µ4) > 0: The mean difference in response time between low load incompatible trials and low load neutral trials will be equal to or lower than the mean difference in response times between high load incompatible trials and high load neutral trials.

Those hypotheses are terribly verbose but I don't know how to simplify them.

To me the logic seems to be: (A-B)-(C-D)>0.

Testing the hypothesis is basically a two part process.  1) Subtract condition A from condition B = x. 2) Subtract condition C from condition D = y. IF x > y then reject the null.

Am I allowed to state the hypotheses in this way and does it even make sense? While I'm on the topic, would it be preferable to do a t-test to compare x and y before I can reject the null?